# How to create tunnel to utilize for telnet connection

Tags: linux, sockets, firewall, telnet, tunnel

The scenario is as follows:

Machine A is located behind client firewall. The machine runs telnetd. This is Linux machine with Python 2.5.4 installed. I do not know the IP addy of the router and firewall is not open incoming. outgoing firewall is open.

Machine B (Windows machine) is a server with well known IP address. I can install any programs I want on either machine.

The idea is that I want Machine A to open a socket to machine B. Then I want to hold that socket and use to run a telnet session from Machine B to Machine A telnetd server.

Is there any freeware that does this?
Thoughts?
Thanks!

Comment: telnet is soooo *1980s*... I cannot believe you're running telnet in this day and age.... whatever happened to ssh?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to setup an SSH tunnel, if possible.

- [Some instructions for Ubuntu](http://embraceubuntu.com/2006/12/08/ssh-tunnel-socks-proxy-forwarding-secure-browsing/)
- [A LifeHacker article on ssh SOCKS tunneling in windows](http://lifehacker.com/237227/geek-to-live--encrypt-your-web-browsing-session-with-an-ssh-socks-proxy)
- [And using PuTTY](http://vectrosecurity.com/content/view/67/26/)